# How can I ignore window.onpopstate on page load in safari?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have a page use popstate when user click back button
but in safari browser, popstate fire on page load instead back button click.

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {

        var pathname1 = document.location.pathname;
        if (document.location.pathname === pathname1 && window.history.state.order == initial_order) {
            if (history.state == null) {
                history.pushState({ 'status': 'ongoing' }, null, null);
            }
            window.onpopstate = function (event) {
                const endProgress = confirm("This will end your exam, are you sure you want to go back?");

                    if (endProgress) {
                        window.onpopstate = null;
                        window.location.href = "studentlogout.do";
                    } else {
                        history.pushState(null, null, null);
                    }
            };
        }
    }
```